# PyQt, Quamash, асинхронность и многопоточность

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, инспекция-кода, асинхронность, pyqt

День добрый. Есть оконное приложение написанное на `Python 3.5 + PyQt5`. Приложение представляет из себя параллельный клиент, делающий много запросов к стороннему `API`. Так как приложение оконное, то выполнять асинхронные операции с помощью библиотеки `asyncio` и не блокировать основной поток просто так не получится, используется еще и `Quamash`.

Вопрос встал как раз в реализации параллельного ожидания получения ответа из `API`. Я написал двумя способами: асинхронным и многопоточным. Привожу упрощенные варианты, попытаюсь отразить саму суть. Первый выглядит так:

```
async def get_async(items):
    to_do = []
    for item in items: # items содержит 35 объектов, соответственно будет выполнено 35 запросов к API
        url = "..." # подготовка url адреса
        params = {...} # подготовка GET параметорв
        to_do.append(asend_request(url, params))
        to_do_iter = asyncio.as_completed(to_do)

    for future in to_do_iter:
        # получение результата и последующая обработка
        result = await future

async def asend_request(url, params):
    response = await aiohttp.request("GET", url, params=params)
    json = await response.json()
    return json
```

Всё прекрасно работает, поток не блокируется, но проблема в том, что это выполняется в одном потоке и он перегружается. Окно начинает тормозить, резко приложение начинает жрать много оперативы.
Второй вариант:

```
async def get_async(items):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = {}
    with QThreadExecutor(35) as executor:
        for item in items:
            url = "..."
            params = {...}
            future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, send_request, url, params)
            futures[future] = (item, url, params)

        for future in futures.keys():
            item, url, params = futures[future]
            response = await future

def send_request(url, params):
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return response.json()
```

Этот вариант работает гораздо лучше, во первых он обрабатывает ответы в 3 раза быстрее. Во вторых, окно ни капли не подвисает. Ну это как я понял из-за того, что создается 35 реальных потоков. Но это и настораживает. Как я читал, каждый отдельный поток операционной системы - это большие расходы памяти. По идее тут хватило бы и двух. Один отвечает за обработку окна, а второй асинхронно делает запросы, в таком случае основной поток не перегрузиться и окно не будет лагать.

Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь всё свести к асинхронному варианту и не создавать на каждый запрос по одному потоку, но и так, что бы основной поток не перегружался?
Пытался внутри `QThreadExecutor` вызвать асинхронную функцию, ничего не получилось, все сводится к числу потоков, которое я передаю конструктору `executor`'а.

Comment: посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, в тех примерах создается `PyQt`'овский поток и в нем выполняются нужные вычисления. Я попробовал так сделать, выделить отдельный поток и в нем асинхронно загружать данные. Ничего не получилось, я вообще не могу использовать `asyncio` внутри этого потока. Вылетает ошибка, что нет `event loop`'a, или что-то вроде такого.

Comment: Вот описание ошибки: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.`

Comment: Не ясно, к чему здесь больше одного потока -- все время на IO уходит. В первом варианте [не хватает session,](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31795242/4279) [semaphore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722204/4279), чтобы ограничить количество одновременных соединений до 35.

Comment: @jfs, с семафором еще хуже, и с ним еще часто эксепшны вылетают

Comment: @Klym учитывая что semaphore сам по себе никак к исключениям не ведёт, у вас что-то другое сломано. К примеру, get_async() явно сломана.

Comment: @jfs, ну в ней обработка результата сложная, я её тут не привел, да и смысла нету. Может там что-то, в общем, я еще пороюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю ответ тут [каждый поток должен иметь собственный цикл событий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063403/python-running-autobahnpython-asyncio-websocket-server-in-a-separate-subproce)

[asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe),
[concurrent.futures.Executor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor)